# Pandas groubpy index count nonblanks

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a dataset similar to the one presented below:

```
index  qty change  price change
A          +
B          +            -
B
C
C          -
C          -  
C          -
D                       +
```

I would like to group/aggregate this in such a way that any non-blank instances of qty change or price change are counted at the index level. Meaning, I would like to have the above-noted dataset summarized thusly:

```
index  qty change  price change
A          1
B          1            1
C          3
D                       1
```

I have been playing with `groupby().count()` but seem to be having trouble isolating only nonblanks (these columns will only ever be populated with + or -, so if it is easier to isolate that way that works as well).

Any thoughts on how best to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not optimal nor elegant, but one thing you can do is create auxiliary columns, with value 1 for '+' or '-' and 0 when blank, and use sum as aggregator

Comment: @Inox Thanks! This is similar to chrisaycock's response below. Thanks for chiming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can set-up boolean columns whose values depend on whether the source column is non-blank:

```
df['price_bool'] = df.price_change != ' '
df['qty_bool'] = df.qty_change != ' '
```

Now I can use a simple aggregation:

```
In [53]: df.groupby('index')[['price_bool', 'qty_bool']].sum()
Out[53]:
       price_bool  qty_bool
index
A               0         1
B               1         1
C               0         3
D               1         0
```